# android gradle build system - what does path mean in compile project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

given the following line in an android build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
flavor1Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
```

What does "path" mean here ?  I believe configuaration refers to the buildtype and flavor you would like to compile with but what does path mean here ? 
if you notice lib1 is a library or jar, etc but its not proving a path to itself so what does path mean here ?
I got the code example [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a path to a module in your project: a module `lib1` in the project root level `:`.

`flavor1Compile` is your configuration name, `project` declares a project dependency and `(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')` supplies a map of arguments to the project dependency.

Further reading for this particular Gradle DSL: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html

Comment: so, compile project(":SliderPreference") with no path uses the default configuration, thats fine. but lets say my path was to a module was located in a subfolder called "coolLibraries". then can i add the project dependency like this: flavor1Compile project(path: 'coolLibraries:lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')